# Keras trained regression model predicts same output for all set of test features

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, regression

I am trying to build a regression model that predicts the 'Ratings' for movies using the dataset https://www.kaggle.com/shubhammehta21/movie-lens-small-latest-dataset. However after training the model, predictions outputs the same value for all test features. I have read previous similar features that suggested adjusting learning rates, no. of features and checking that the model predicting is the same as the trained model. None of these has worked for me.

I load the data and process it:

```
links= pd.read_csv('../input/movie-lens-small-latest-dataset/links.csv')
movies=pd.read_csv('../input/movie-lens-small-latest-dataset/movies.csv')
...

dataset=movies.merge(ratings,on='movieId').merge(tags,on='movieId').merge(links,on='movieId')

to_drop='title','genres','timestamp_x','timestamp_y','userId_y','imdbId','tmdbId']

dataset.drop(columns=to_drop,inplace=True)

dataset=pd.get_dummies(dataset)
```

The code shows how I build the regression model. I have tried adjusting the number of neuron and layers, however, that has not influenced the output.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=1586, kernel_initializer='zero', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='linear'))
# Compile model
adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam,metrics=['mse','mae'])

model.summary()
history = model.fit(train_dataset,train_labels,batch_size=30, epochs=10,verbose=1, validation_split=0.3)
score = model.evaluate(validation_dataset,validation_labels)
print("Test score:", score)
```

Whenever I try to predict the test dataset:

```
model.predict(test_dataset)
```

It predicts the value of

```
3.97
```

on all values. I am expecting a range of values between 0 - 5.

Comment: `kernel_initializer='normal'` is not recommended; remove the argument so as to revert to the [default](https://keras.io/layers/core/) `glorot-uniform` (defaults are there for a reason, except if you have a *real* reason to change them, which I trust you don't have here...)

Comment: @desertnaut Thank you. I removed it and noticed a variation in the prediction output. I am now getting a range between 3.7 and 4.2  . I guess adjusting layers, epochs, no. of Neurons would help with that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never (I mean, *never*) use `kernel_initializer='zero'` - to be honest, I am surprised that the option even exists in Keras!

Also, `kernel_initializer='normal'` is not recommended.

As a first step, remove **all** `kernel_initializer` arguments, so as to revert to the [default](https://keras.io/layers/core/) and recommended one, `kernel_initializer='glorot-uniform'`; keep in mind that defaults are there for a reason (usually they work well), and you should change them only if you *really* have a reason to do so (which I trust you don't have here) and you know what you are doing.

If you still don't get what you would expect, experiment with other parameters (no. of layers/neurons, more epochs etc); you should leave the learning rate (`lr`) of Adam optimizer as is for starters (it's also one of these default values that seem to work nicely across cases).